# Vue html comment handling

Tags: html, vue.js, tags, comments, conditional-comments

I'm using Vue to produce some html template, I need to include the html conditional comments as per code below.

```js
var productTemplate = new Vue({
    el: '#myApp'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.8/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="myApp">
    <div class="some-content">
        This is some content
    </div>

    <!--[if mso]>
      <div>
          this div will only be shown if the condition in the comment is true, in this case the condition is:
          if ( mso (microsoft office) == the html rendering engine) {
            show the html code between the [if mso] and the [endif]
          }
      </div>
    <![endif]-->

    <div class="some-other-content">
        This is some content
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I open my html page in the browser the html code between the conditional comment is completely removed even though I actually need it to be there.

How can I make Vue include these comments in the template's view?

Comment: `conditional comments` means show/ hide ?

Comment: Share more details and example of both conditionall output?

Comment: Added more details.

Comment: @user2486 These conditional comments: https://www.sitepoint.com/internet-explorer-conditional-comments/

Comment: I’m not sure vue is at fault here: if you remove the vue script include, does the issue still arise?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Vue 2.4.0+, you can set the [`comments`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#comments) option to `true` inside the component if you want to preserve comments in the component's template.

```js
var productTemplate = new Vue({
    comments: true,  // <-- Add this
    el: '#myApp'
});
```

Comment: You made my day

Comment: Restrictions: This option is only available in the full build, with in-browser compilation.

Comment: what a legend himself

Comment: Note for those who are using Vue 3 render function: there is a function called `createCommentVNode`

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Vue does delete the HTML comment.</strike>

One way I can think of is to bind your comments in a variable and output the variable through v-html directive.

EDIT: I tested it in a wrong dev env, so here is a link about the question from the Vue.js GitHub issue. https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6177

```js
var productTemplate = new Vue({
    el: '#myApp',
    comments: true,
    data: {
      comments: `    <!--[if mso]>
      <div>
          this div will only be shown if the condition in the comment is true, in this case the condition is:
          if ( mso (microsoft office) == the html rendering engine) {
            show the html code between the [if mso] and the [endif]
          }
      </div>
    <![endif]-->`
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.8/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="myApp">
    <div class="some-content">
        This is some content
    </div>
    <!-- Comments -->
    <div v-html="comments"> {{ comments }} </div>

    <div class="some-other-content">
        This is some content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This was the best solution for my needs!

Comment: @CliffHelsel glad it still helps after 2 years.