# Laravel 8: All HTML comments and [MSO] tags are being stripped from email HTML body

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-mix

I don't know if it's related, but this happening once we started to use laravel-mix for css and js files. For some reason all tags like `<!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->` in the email blade are being stripped off when we receive the email. Which totally breaks the email formatting. Does anyone know if there are any settings for blade compilation, which tell the engine to strip/keep HTML comments?

Edited: we are using `view('email.body',compact('data))->render()` function to render the HTML

Comment: if, its for email, why do you  comment it?

Comment: thats an old way to tell outlook or ie to use additional tags, like table etc

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out. We were rendering email body and passing to the preview page, which was handled by Vuejs. By default Vuejs strips all the HTML comments.

The solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47426675/vue-html-comment-handling)

just add HTML comments handling for Vuejs

```
const app = new Vue({
    comments: true, <-- Add this
    el: '#app',
```

to your `resources/js/app.js`